# onTextChanged doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse

I need something such that when users enter numbers in editText part,the modulo of the total of numbers should be shown to the screen at the same time.So I used onTextChanged , I convert characters to int and set this value to a TextView.It didn't work.Problem occurs probably due to converting charactersequence to int.

```
    editText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           }

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after          {
           }

           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
           TextView showNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showNumber);
           int i=0;
           int n= Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
           i=(i+n)%10;
           showNumber.setText(i);
    }});
```

Comment: What kind of problem occurs? Be more specific when posting a question. If there's a crash, please post the logcat trace. If the result is not as you wish it to be, tell us what you receive and what you expect.

Comment: Use int n= Integer.parseInt(s.toString().trim()); instead of int n= Integer.parseInt(s.toString());

Comment: When I start typing numbers into editText program has stopped.

Comment: Hey i tested your code. There are many errors. Use my code, i just inserted it below.

Comment: Thank you very much ,same problem still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, quick research on Android's documentation reveals that `EditText` extends `TextView` which has this method:

```
public final void setText (int resid)
```

Your `i` which you pass as argument to `setText()` method is of `int` type, which means that it's being used as a resource id to be converted to text. It can't find resource in `string.xml` with such id so I assume that it crashes.

What you have to do is to convert `i` to `CharSequence` and pass it to `setText()` method like this:

```
showNumber.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
showNumber.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

As per your code, you are initializing `i = 0`. There is no need to add the `n` with `i` since it is always `zero`

Answer (score 1):

Declare textview in onCreate()

Try this :

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

           }

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)          {
           }

           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
                int n= Integer.valueOf(s.toString().trim());
                   i=(i+n)%10;
                   textView.setText(""+i);
           }});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**main.xnl**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtModulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    private EditText edtInput;
    private TextView txtModulo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        edtInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtInput);
        txtModulo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtModulo);

        edtInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.toString().trim().length()>0){
                    txtModulo.setText(String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(s.toString().trim())%10)));
                }else{
                    txtModulo.setText("");
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 ditText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   ditText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       }

       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after          {
       }

       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
       TextView showNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showNumber);
       int i=0;
       int n= Integer.parseInt(ditText1.getText().toString());
       i=(i+n)%10;
       showNumber.setText(Integer.toString(i));
}});
```

Comment: try now that time integer is not converted to string which used to set the text for show number

Comment: I can still see `setText` being passed an `Integer`

Comment: its for passing resource ID you will get a resource not found exception at that time

Comment: Yes you are proving my point that it will crash as there is no guarantee that such an id exists.